# Android animation not playing

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to get a frame by frame animation to run on android 2.2 in a 2.2 vm machine using eclipse and i cannot for the life of me get it to run. It just sits there on the first frame of the animation.

Here is my activity code:

```
public class SpriteAnimationActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
        ImageView lView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        AnimationDrawable lAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)lView.getBackground();
        lAnimation.start();
    }
}
```

Here is my animation list xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a2"   android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/a3"   android:duration="100" />    
</animation-list>
```

I am using the imageView widget on my main screen to display the image by setting the background. I tried to follow the guide here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html but I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Did your animation worked ? else i have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can get help:

- [Simple tween animation example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152254/simple-tween-animation-example)
- [Android animation example on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android-animation-example/)

Comment: Thanks for those additional resources, the google code one was specially useful

Answer (score 1):

You have to start animation forcefully...

```
 ImageView lView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            lView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_animation_list);
            final AnimationDrawable lAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)lView.getBackground();


    //        Button btn=
            findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     lAnimation.start();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the animation manually through button click listener or use the onWindowFocusChange listener like below

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus) {
        lAnimation.start(); 
    }
}
```