# how to move image from bottom to top in android?

Tags: android, animation, move, slide

In my android app i have an image at the bottom of the screen. I want to move it towards the top of the screen by clicking it. And the image should get disappear when it reaches to the top of the screen. How can i do the .Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: sir plz suggest any demo or tutorial related to my problem.Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152254/simple-tween-animation-example

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this:--

http://obviam.net/index.php/moving-images-on-the-screen-with-androi/